# Function to return true from an if conditional nested in a for loop

Tags: php, function, boolean

I'm having a problem and don't know if this is a good solution or if I'm nowhere near.
I want to return true of false if the expiry date is bigger than today, the below code is doing fine except I can't use the expiry variable to be returned so I can use that value.

Any help or what's wrong with this code would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
function fileRange($files){
    $today  =   date('Ymd');
    $expiry_date = '';
    $expiry = '';
    for( $i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++)
    {
        $file = $files[$i];
        $expiry_date    .=   $file['expiry_date'];
        $splited_array = str_split($expiry_date, 8);
        if ($splited_array[$i] > $today){
            $expiry =   true;
        }else{
            $expiry =   false;
        }
        /* var_dump($expiry);
         Here the variable works just fine, returning all     
         the possible combinations but after the for loop
         I can't access all the values but only the last 
         one */
    }

    return $expiry;
}
```

This is the $file parameter

```
if (fileRange($files))
```

This is the $files parameter

```
[0]=>
 array(2) {
  ["file"]=> array(21) {
            ["ID"]=>  int(2904)
            ["id"]=>  int(2904)
            ["title"]=> string(55) "..."
            ["filename"]=> string(58) "..."
            ["filesize"]=> int(434223)
            ["url"]=> string(106) "..."
            ["link"]=> string(90) "..."
            ["alt"]=>  string(0) ""
            ["author"]=> string(1) "1"
            ["description"]=> string(0) ""
            ["caption"]=> string(0) ""
            ["name"]=> string(53) "..."
            ["status"]=> string(7) "inherit"
            ["uploaded_to"]=> int(615)
            ["date"]=> string(19) "2019-02-19 15:55:20"
            ["modified"]=> string(19) "2019-02-19 15:55:20"
            ["menu_order"]=> int(0)
            ["mime_type"]=> string(15) "application/pdf"
            ["type"]=>  string(11) "application"
            ["subtype"]=> string(3) "pdf"
            ["icon"]=> string(58) "..."
        }
    ["expiry_date"]=>  string(8) "20190802"
}
```

Comment: Show us an example of what you are passing on the `$files` parameter please

Comment: _NOTE:_ You are in a loop so this `$expiry =   true;`  or this `$expiry =   false;` line will OVERWRITE `$expiry` each time round the loop

Comment: If you want all 50 results you will have to make `$expiry` an array also

Comment: Continuing on from @RiggsFolly's first point, you might need to [`break`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) out of the loop.

Comment: @RiggsFolly added the $files parameter

Comment: _The first question I should have asked is:_ Do you want to stop the loop on the First TRUE or the first FALSE or do you want all 50 results returned

Comment: @RiggsFolly all 50 results returned

Comment: _Small point_ This line `$splited_array = str_split($expiry_date, 8);` does not actually achieve anything useful as `$file['expiry_date']` is an 8 character string to start with

Comment: Yep, you're correct, thanks @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your `$expiry` variable as an array

```
function fileRange($files){
    $today  =   date('Ymd');
    $expiry_date = '';
    $expiry = array();
    for( $i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++)
    {
        $file = $files[$i];
        $expiry_date    .=   $file['expiry_date'];
        $splited_array = str_split($expiry_date, 8);
        if ($splited_array[$i] > $today){
            $expiry[] =   true;
        }else{
            $expiry[] =   false;
        }
    }

    return $expiry;
}
```

Comment: You can also replace the complete `if/else`-block with just: `$expiry[] = splited_array[$i] > $today;`.  or even `$expire[] = substr($expiry_date, 0, 8) > $today;` so you can remove the line above the if-statement as well.

Comment: You have helped a lot. Thanks!